# CSVDE on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a brand new Win Server 2012 R2 image. I want to run some csvde scripts, but I get:

```
'csvde' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

On Win 8 I used to install `Remote Server Administration Tools` to be able to use CSVDE, but now I can't find anything like this for Server 2012. How can I add this feature?

Comment: Can you verify if the binary is present? `dir /s /b C:\*csvde.exe` from a `cmd` prompt. Should be one in C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64.  If it's there, check `ECHO %PATH%`, your environment might be broken.

Comment: Non of the paths contains csvde.exe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you need to install the RSAT Active Directory Tools.  From an elevated Powershell prompt try the following.

Get status of the feature

```
 Get-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-Tools
```

Should display something like this...

```
 Display Name                                            Name                         Install State
 ------------                                            ----                       -------------
    [ ] AD DS and AD LDS Tools                      RSAT-AD-Tools                  Available
```

Then to install the feature:

```
 Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-Tools
```

Comment: Yeah, meanwhile I found it. It can be installed from the server roles/features as well. Thanks.